# Tuple error searching arrays created by postgresql

Tags: python, arrays

I have some arrays with the same customer names on different orders, what I am trying to do and the following:

1 - Take the name of customers and compare to return when it is the same, solving the problem of random order;

2 - After obtaining this comparison, the output should be as follows:

The solution below resolves if I use the arrays manually, but when I enter through the database, I have an error as output

It works:

```
array1 = [['CLIENT1', '2', '3'],['CLIENT2', '3', '4'],['CLIENT3', '4', '5']]
array2 = [['CLIENT3', '2', '3'],['CLIENT2', '3', '4'],['CLIENT1', '4', '5']]
array3 = [['CLIENT2', '2', '3'],['CLIENT1', '3', '4'],['CLIENT3', '4', '5']]
```

**The output should look like this:** Customer Name, value contained in array1 for this customer name, value contained in array2 for this customer name and value contained in array3 for this customer name

**SCRIPT**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import psycopg2
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta

# create script head
print ('----------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print ('Initializing script: '+str(date.today()))
print ('----------------------------------------------------------------------------')

################################################################################
# Set connection to postgres
connpostgres = psycopg2.connect("host='192.168.0.245'"
                        " dbname='metrics'"
                        " user='postgres'"
            " password=pass123")
cursorpost = connpostgres.cursor()  

################################################################################
# Create arrays
################################################################################

cursorpost.execute(rz_collect)
rz_collect = cursorpost.fetchall()
array_rz_collect = []
for row in rz_collect:
    array_rz_collect.append(row)

cursorpost.execute(sql_on_off)
sql_on_off = cursorpost.fetchall()
array_sql_on_off = []
for row in sql_on_off:
    array_sql_on_off.append(row)

cursorpost.execute(sql_gaps_so)
sql_gaps_so = cursorpost.fetchall()
array_sql_gaps_so = []
for row in sql_gaps_so:
    array_sql_gaps_so.append(row)

cursorpost.execute(sql_gaps_db)
sql_gaps_db = cursorpost.fetchall()
array_sql_gaps_db = []
for row in sql_gaps_db:
    array_sql_gaps_db.append(row)

cursorpost.execute(sql_gaps_sap)
sql_gaps_sap = cursorpost.fetchall()
array_sql_gaps_sap = []
for row in sql_gaps_sap:
    array_sql_gaps_sap.append(row)

################################################################################
# Check and align arrays

# Initialize a dictionary with key = client name, value = list of client entries
result = {}

# Add values from array1
for client_info in array_rz_collect:
    # Parse current entry
    client_name = client_info[0]
    client_values = client_info[1:]
    print(client_values)

    # Add previous values if exitant
    if client_name in result.keys():
        client_values.extend(result[client_name])

    # Update clients dictionary
    result[client_name] = client_values

# Add values from array2
for client_info in array_sql_on_off:
    # Parse current entry
    client_name = client_info[0]
    client_values = client_info[1:]

    # Add previous values if exitant
    if client_name in result.keys():
        client_values.extend(result[client_name])

    # Update clients dictionary
    result[client_name] = client_values

# Add values from array3
for client_info in array_sql_gaps_so:
    # Parse current entry
    client_name = client_info[0]
    client_values = client_info[1:]

    # Add previous values if exitant
    if client_name in result.keys():
        client_values.extend(result[client_name])

    # Update clients dictionary
    result[client_name] = client_values

# Print result information
for client_name, client_values in result.items():
    print("Result: " + str(client_name) + ", " + str(client_values))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  File "SCRIPT.py", line 166, in <module>
    client_values.extend(result[client_name])
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

**DESERIED OUTPUT**

```
Result: CLIENT1, ['3', '4', '4', '5', '2', '3']
Result: CLIENT2, ['2', '3', '3', '4', '3', '4']
Result: CLIENT3, ['4', '5', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `cursorpost.fetchall()` (`rz_collect`) is a list of tuples.

In the code,

```
rz_collect = cursorpost.fetchall()
array_rz_collect = []
for row in rz_collect:
    array_rz_collect.append(row)
```

`array_rz_collect` is same as `rz_collect`, therefore it too is a list of tuples.
Side note: That `for loop` is unnecessary, you can directly operate on `rz_collect`

In the code,

```
for client_info in array_rz_collect:
    # Parse current entry
    client_name = client_info[0]
    client_values = client_info[1:]
    print(client_values)

    # Add previous values if exitant
    if client_name in result.keys():
        client_values.extend(result[client_name])
```

`client_info` is a tuple.
`client_values` is also a tuple since you are just slicing another tuple. Tuples do not have the `extend` method since they are not mutable like lists.

A simple fix to your problem is to convert the tuple to list.

```
client_info = list(client_info) # new line
client_name = client_info[0]
client_values = client_info[1:]
```

Comment: Just a question, any idea how to keep the array order array_rz_collect, array_sql_on_off, array_sql_gaps_so ... At print time?

Comment: And set null on missing values

Comment: Instead of normal dictionary you can use an OrderedDict. import statement at the top - `from collections import OrderedDict`. Instead of `result = {}`, make it `result = OrderedDict()`. With this the dictionary will maintain insertion order.

Comment: Can you be specific on the second comment? Missing values, where?

Comment: the question of ordering of the insertion occurred perfectly, when I speak of null values, it would be for example:

I have an array4 = [['CLIENT2', '2', '3'], ['CLIENT1', '3', '4'], ['CLIENT3', '4',]]

where client3 is missing a value, such as passing this value by default 0 or 'null'

Comment: Because this way I'll have a structure pattern to create a table in the database and do the INSERT